# Hints/ Solution in finding a formula $\phi(n)$ for a binary square matrix

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I don't know if this is a famous problem but my professor assigned this for a research project and I am hitting a dead end( I don't know what to do next).

Note: In $\phi(n)$ ; $n=rows=columns$ and this function throws out total combination of matrices that satisfies the following rule:

Rule for this square binary matrix: 
**Every Row and Column has two 1's.**

So,

- $$\phi(2)=1$$ \begin{bmatrix}    1 1 \\    1 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
- $$\phi(3)=6$$ 
  I can't write out all the possible matrices for $n=3$ but this is one of them (btw i did this by hand):
  \begin{bmatrix}    0 1 1 \\    1 0 1 \\ 1 1 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}

According to a program made by my friend, he told me:

- $$\phi(4)=90$$
- $$\phi(5)=2040$$

Comment: Do you know about OEIS? Using your initial values, you can search for this sequence there; it's [OEIS sequence A001499](http://oeis.org/A001499).

Comment: @joriki  Didn't know about this but pretty cool! Thanx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a Sock Distribution Problem, a solution related exactly to the matrices described in the question.  Here is the solution:

$$\phi(n)= \frac{n(n-1)^2}{2}\ [(2n-3)\phi_{n-2}+(n-2)^2\phi_{n-3}]\hspace{1cm} \forall n\geq3$$